# Proper usage of Prefix "UN" is there a word as "UNSWAPPING"

Tags: prefixes

A closed group in Facebook bash me for asking them if there's such word as "UNSWAPPING" I reached Google and Dictionaries of which I failed to find this word. Yes, there's an adjective "unswapped" but I never found "UNSWAPPING" please help me. I want to know the precise answer. Thank you!

Comment: What do you understand by this term? More context, please!

Comment: The prefix un- can be used in two related but different ways. 1) as a verb in any form, talking about reversing an action which has been taken. 2) as a participle-adjective (eg "unswapped") indicating that an available action has not been performed at all. The latter form is potentially ambiguous between the two usages, unless context is added. "Unswapping" seems fine to me, but you won't find every possible "un-" verb in dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was confused because I even searched for different words and in Dictionaries online there's the participle/adjective with the prefix "un" of words, but for "swapping" I never seen any... have you ever tried to use this word before?

Comment: Hi, here's what I'm talking about here. It's there post in Facebook of which they got me confused.

Comment: BIRTHDAY SHORT EVENT FOR ADMIN EMZ


RULE
MORE LIKE BUT UNSWAPPING
IT WILL BE 1ST PLACE

MORE PHOTO COMMMENT =EDIT PICTURE BY ADMIN EMZ
IT WILL BE 2ND PLACE

HIGHEST FLOODING COMMENT 
HAPPY BIRTHDAY EMZ..
3RD PLACE

Answer (score 2):

The interesting thing about "unswapping" (putting exactly two things, which have been swapped, back into their original positions) is that it is semantically equivalent to  "re-swapping" and logically equivalent to "swapping".  It's just another swap.

And after you do this, the two things might SEEM "unswapped", but they will have been swapped twice!

So, yes, you could use unswap, but there are better alternatives. In my opinion, you would be more easily understood (as restoring a prior state) if you said "swap(ped/ping) back".

.

Comment: Thank you for your response :) I'll re-type here the exact words they used for that competition and please give a comment

Comment: BIRTHDAY SHORT EVENT FOR ADMIN EMZ
............................................................................

RULE
MORE LIKE BUT UNSWAPPING
IT WILL BE 1ST PLACE
................................................
MORE PHOTO COMMMENT =EDIT PICTURE BY ADMIN EMZ
IT WILL BE 2ND PLACE
..........................................................................................
HIGHEST FLOODING COMMENT 


.............................................................................
FLOODING COMMENT 2ND HIGHEST
6TH PLACE

Comment: Why don't just say.. "no swapping"?